# Remove row group from crosstab?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, crosstab

I have jasper report with crosstab created in iReport tool. Is there a way to remove a row group from crosstab without recreating the report again?

Comment: `without recreating the report again` - What do you mean? Without compiling?

Comment: I mean without recreating the crosstab again without adding the row group I like to remove